# Override the function twentytwelve_scripts_styles in a child theme

Tags: functions, child-theme, theme-twenty-twelve

I want to overide the function which enqueues scripts and styles in the theme Twenty Twelve using its child functions.php.

I followed this [guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-overriding-parent-theme-functions-in-your-child-theme--cms-22623) but can't get it to work.

Can someone suggest a possible workaround?

For quick reference the function is [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/functions.php#L131-L155)

I don't want to use `wp_deregister_style`/`script` as I want to keep my code clean.

Comment: I cannot see how using `wp_deregister_style()` would **DIRTY** your code. Please explain

Comment: I didn't mean dirty exactly. Just the number of lines due dependency management. Also, once I remove the parent function and write my own function, it is clearer when I come back to it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the entire `twentytwelve_scripts_styles` function, you have to remove the action hook :

```
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwelve_scripts_styles' );
```

However, this code have to execute after the function is being hooked by Twenty Twelve code, and before the action is fired (because after it's too late). The child theme `functions.php` file is loaded before the Twenty Twelve one, so you have to call `remove_action` from an action that fires before `wp_enqueue_scripts`, for example `init`.

```
add_action( 'init', 'answer_215713_override_twentytwelve_script' );
function answer_215713_override_twentytwelve_script(){
    remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwelve_scripts_styles' );
}
```

The tutorial that you linked says :

> [...] you need to attach this function to a hook which will fire after the hook which the parent theme function is attached to. This is because you can't remove the action before it's been fired.

I think this is wrong. The opposite is true : you have to attach your function to a hook that will fires **before** the hook it was attached by the parent theme, or else it will be to late to cancel the action. In fact, you can't remove actions **after** they have been fired (it's useless).

Comment: Thanks. That part was so ingrained that I never realized it!

Your code works.